# Cordova: login with facebook using javascript api not working

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova

I am using JavaScript login with facebook api in my app.It is working fine in web app.But when i build app for android then on button click it shows window for adding facebook credentials for login,but on submitting credentials it shows white screen and redirect function does not work.I am new in cordova applications.So can someone tell me is it right to use JavaScript for facebook login in cordova app or there is something else for this.Below is my code

HTML part

```
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <div id="user-info"></div>
 <a href="#" class="f_icon" id='fb-auth'>Sign in with Facebook</a>
```

js of facebook

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   FB.init({
    appId: '33XXXXXXXXXX',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true
});

function updateButton(response) {
    var button = document.getElementById('fb-auth');

    if (response.authResponse) {

        FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        });
        button.onclick = function() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                        var user_info = {
                            name: response.name,
                            email: response.email,
                            fb_id: response.id,
                            gender: response.gender
                        };

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'ws/webservice.php?mode=facebook_login',
                            data: user_info,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(json) {
                                if (json.status == "success") {
                                                                                                      window.localStorage.setItem("session_id",json.session_id);

                  var session_id  = window.localStorage.getItem("session_id");

                                    window.location.href = "dashboard.html";

                                } else {

                                }
                            },
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'email'
            });
        }
    } else {
        //user is not connected to your app or logged out
        button.innerHTML = 'Sign in with Facebook';
        button.onclick = function() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

                        var user_info = {
                            name: response.name,
                            email: response.email,
                            link: response.link,
                            fb_id: response.id,
                            gender: response.gender
                        };
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'webservice.php?mode=facebook_login',
                            data: user_info,
                            type: "POST",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function(json) {
                                if (json.status == "success") {

                        window.localStorage.setItem("session_id", json.session_id);

                  var session_id =  window.localStorage.getItem("session_id");
                   window.location.href = "dashboard.html";

                                } else {

                                }
                            },
                        });


                    });
                } else {
                    //user cancelled login or did not grant authorization
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'email'
            });
        }
    }
}

// run once with current status and whenever the status changes
FB.getLoginStatus(updateButton);
// FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', updateButton);
};
(function() {
var e = document.createElement('script');
e.async = true;
e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used This code **https://github.com/ccoenraets/OpenFB** and in app-browser to solve my problem.

Here is one more plugin on that **https://github.com/krisrak/jquery-cordova-oauth2**

Answer (score 1):

Since cordova isn't a web app, it doesn't have a domain, hence it doesn't have any page to return to within the "site". To get Facebook connect working on cordova, you should really read up on how to implement plugins.

Here's the plugin for Facebook Connect for both Android and iOS:
https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Assuming you use cordova 3.3.0 and up.

Comment: thanks for your reply.is this plugin the only way to use login with facebook?

Comment: I assume you can use the inappbrowser to show facebook's login screen with your own redirect, and then analyze the callback you get, but this is not the way it's meant to be used, imho.

Comment: In cordova do i need to create different apps on facebook for different platforms or i just need to create only one app?

Comment: One Facebook app for all platforms.